# No puedo despaticionar mi disco duro en Windows

Tags: windows, windows10

estaba a punto de eliminar mi disco F: para luego unir este espacio con el disco C: pero mi portatil dice que quedan 2,86 GB de espacio siendo utilizado. Estoy seguro de que borré todo e inclusive borré la papelera, pero no me deja formatearlo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No esta usando esa ruta windows para su archivo temporal de memoria? y ojo que en realidad este sitio es sobre programacion...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no versa sobre alguna duda de programación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema me parece de indexación entre las particiones.

Haz una tabla de partición limpia, me resulta extraño que tengas dos particiones antes de la partición de la instalación de windows.

Normalmente Windows deja un esquema de partición tal que:
/sda: sda1 [MBR] {La partición de 500MB} sda2 [Particion con Windows]

Toquetear la partición de MBR de Windows es algo sensible, y facilmente puedes tener un error de arranque.

---

Te diría que intentaras copiar la MBR y la partición de la instalación a otro disco duro, [PARTICION entera, de hecho te resultaría más seguro copiar el HDD entero], formatear el disco duro objetivo, crear las particiones y volver a copiarlas integras por volumenes y no por archivos. Aun así, es casi un experimento.

La solución buena es copiar a nivel de ficheros toda tu data(copiar y pegar a otro disco duro), formatear el disco duro bien (debe de estar desmontado, hazlo con un USB-LIVE) y finalmente instalar desde 0 un S.O a tu elección. Si vas a instalar más de un S.O, empieza por Windows.